# "invalid Domain for site key" issue in Captcha in contact us form in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, captcha, domain

While opening contact us form it shows error like below
[image]

Please provide me a solution to sort out this.

Comment: The captcha you are configured with wrong domain key.

Comment: Take a look at this https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/security-google-recaptcha.html

Answer (score 1):

Go to recaptcha admin

> https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/

Click on Setting :
[image]

There you can see the sites that you configured for the Recaptcha . 
The v2 is the one with checkbox option . 
Copy the reCAPTCHA keys:
[image]
and paste them in the admin panel :
[image]

Comment: I have done as you said , but bothing works at frontend

Comment: Check this responses https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735694/recaptcha-error-invalid-domain-for-site-key , they might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Follow the below steps:
1. Go to https://www.google.com/recaptcha
2. Choose reCAPTCHA Type, for example, reCAPTCHA V2, Invisible reCAPTCHA or Invisible reCAPTCHA 2.
3. Regenerate private and public keys.
4. Insert new private and public keys into the Magento site.
5. Then change "reCaptcha type" in the Magento site.
Refer below link for more details:
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/security-google-recaptcha.html
Image: recaptcha.png
```